# Запуск node.js на 443 порту за nginx (nginx как обратный прокси-сервер)

Tags: linux, node.js, nginx, debian

ОС: Debian;

Есть серверная часть, написана на node.js, как запустить его на 443 порту, пишу в nginx.conf вот так и не работает:

```
server {
    # IP, который мы будем слушать
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  site.ru;

    keepalive_timeout    60;
    ssl_certificate      ТУТ_МОЙ_АДРЕС_ДО_SSL_СЕРТИФИКАТА/certificate_bundled.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  ТУТ_МОЙ_АДРЕС_ДО_SSL_ПРИВАТНОГО_КЛЮЧА/privatekey.key;
    ssl_protocols        TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers          "HIGH:!RC4:!aNULL:!MD5:!kEDH";
    add_header           Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=604800';

    location / {
        # IP и порт, на которых висит node.js
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
```

Захожу на https://site.ru и ничего

Если захожу на http://site.ru:443, то nginx выдает вот это [image: Ошибка nginx "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port"]

Захожу по https://site.ru, выдает теперь[image: Error 403]

Comment: Во первых надо делать `listen  443 ssl;`, а во вторых, вы, не подписали сертификат. Почитайте про настройку `https`.

Comment: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Comment: @And, поправил конфиг, все равно не работает, node запущен на 3000 порту, захожу на site.ru и ничего

Comment: @norbornen, посмотрите, пожалуйста еще раз, поправил конфиг

Comment: Похоже, что **всё у вас правильно**. Просто проверяете неправильно: *"Если захожу на http://site.ru:443"* -- а надо на `https://site.ru` (http{+s+} и *без порта*). Собственно, nginx вам прямым текстом сказал, что не так.

Comment: @D-side, т.е. конфиг верный, а проверять только через https://site.ru?

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы ждать от меня ответа, вы можете сами это проверить и задать уже следующий уточняющий вопрос (или не задать, если взлетит).

Comment: @D-side, вроде теперь лучше, но выбивает ошибку 403, прикрепил скриншот выше

Comment: Это уже определённо не от nginx прилетело, так что это успех! А чтобы понять что приложению (на ноде) не понравилось, надо уже логи приложения изучать.

Comment: @D-side, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидных ошибок в настройках я не вижу. Зато вижу в **способе проверки**.

Заметьте, что пользователи же обычно не указывают порты вручную. А вы указываете. Зря.

### HTTP и HTTPS это разные протоколы.

`http://site.ru:443` это обращение к серверу с доменным именем `site.ru` по протоколу HTTP (не HTTPS!) через порт 443, стандартный для HTTPS (не HTTP!).

nginx именно на это и указывает:

> The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

> Запрос на чистом HTTP был отправлен на порт для HTTPS

И исправляется эта ошибка просто указанием всего как есть: `https://site.ru:443`.
Но поскольку 443 **стандартный порт** для HTTPS, указывать его необязательно. Остаётся:

```
https://site.ru
```

То, что и этот URL выдаёт страницу с ошибкой, 403, но не от nginx, это совсем другая проблема, и она связана уже с проксируемым приложением. Нужно изучать логи приложения и если нужно, можно задать об этом отдельный вопрос.

Comment: a-a-a-a-a-a-a!! https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/813384/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0-nginx-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-403