# Обратный прокси сервер на nginx отвечает ошибкой 403

Tags: linux, node.js, nginx, debian, proxy

Есть прокси сервер с такой конфигурацией, нужно чтобы с 443 ше запрос на 3000 порт на котором node.js:

```
server {
    # IP, который мы будем слушать
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  site.ru;

    keepalive_timeout    60;
    ssl_certificate      адрес_до_сертификата/site.ru.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  адрес_до_сертификата/site.ru.key;
    ssl_protocols        TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers          "HIGH:!RC4:!aNULL:!MD5:!kEDH";
    add_header           Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=604800';

    location / {
        # IP и порт, на которых висит node.js
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
```

При переходе по ссылке https://site.ru выбивает ошибку 403, в чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?

[image: Error 403]

Comment: Так а при чём тут прокси и nginx? Вам приложение на 3000'ном порте ответило 403. Что у вас там запущено? Что в его логах?

Comment: @D-side, Отключил node.js сейчас на 3000 порту, ошибка так же, а какие логи нужно смотреть?

Comment: Значит, вам отвечает что-то ещё на том же nginx. Смотрите другие его конфиги.

Comment: @D-side, отвечает vestacp

Comment: Но в чем проблема заключается?

Comment: Видимо, в том, что nginx для вашего запроса не использует приведённый файл настроек, а использует настройки от vestacp. Возможно, этот конфиг лежит в неподходящем месте. А возможно, он некорректен (хоть я сходу и не вижу проблем, это может быть что-то совсем мелкое) и nginx отменяет перезагрузку, обнаружив проблему. Нужны подробности.